# difference between page/xml comments and single line comments in c#

Tags: c#

I am fresher in c#.sorry for asing the very basic question.I saw that single comments are like this(//) and page/xml comments are like this (///).is there any difference in this functionality?why cant we use single line comments instead of page/xml comments?

Comment: Why not search Google for `C# comment types`? This is a very simple question for which answers are plentiful and easy to find.

Comment: If you create an API and want to generate a help document for your users, the `///` xml comments are extremely helpful.  Most help doc apps will generate your help pages off of them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21728435/2589202

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use whatever you want within your code. The advantage of the latter is that your comment can be used for IntelliSense or the generation of code documentation. So basically if you are using Visual Studio, whatever you type in a XML comment will appear for that class/method/property etc.